# fileupload control in usercontrol page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file to a DB using a file upload control inside an user control page. When uploading the file I get an error that there is no file selected in the control.

I have searched the internet for solutions and I have found that I need to add a trigger for the button handling the upload code. Also I have read that I need to add `Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data")`. In my case none seem to work.

aspx file:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" CodeFile="Sessions.aspx.vb" Inherits="Sessions" %>
<%@ Register Src="~/Controls/SessionCtl.ascx" TagName="SessionCtl" TagPrefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>

 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlAddUpdateSession" Visible="false">
                <div style="width: 900px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 20px;">
                    <uc2:SessionCtl runat="server" ID="sessionCtl" />
                </div>
            </asp:Panel>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAddSession" />
        </Triggers>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

ascx file:

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelAddUpdate" runat="server" GroupingText="Add session" Width="95%" CssClass="PanelADD">
    <div id="pnlFileUploadArea" style="align-content: center" class="gvProject">
        <asp:Label ID="label12" Text="Add Log:" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Flow" AutoPostBack="True">
            <asp:ListItem Text="New" Value="0" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="Use Previous" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
        <br />
        <div id="fileUploadContainer" runat="server">
            <div id="fileUploadControl">
                <asp:FileUpload ID="fuSelectedFile" runat="server"size="60"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
    </div>
    <div style="padding: 5px 5px 5px 25px">
        <asp:Button ID="btnAddSession" runat="server" Text="Add" SkinID="fancybutton" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelAddSession" runat="server" Text="Cancel" SkinID="fancybutton" />
    </div>
</asp:Panel>
```

ascx.vb file:

```
    Protected Sub btnAddSession_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddSession.Click
    If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage)) Then
    'validationMessage is a var I use to check if other fields are filled correctly
        If (RadioButtonList1.Items.FindByText("New").Selected = True) Then
            If Not (fuSelectedFile.HasFile) Then
                'upload files
            Else
                validationMessage = "No file selected!"
            End If
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

aspx.vb file:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Page.Form.Attributes.Add("enctype", "multipart/form-data")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can try this**

***ascx file***

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />

<asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload"

OnClick="btnUpload_Click" />

<br />

<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""

Font-Names = "Arial"></asp:Label>
```

***ascx.cs***

***On Button Upload event***

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    // Read the file and convert it to Byte Array

    string filePath = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;  

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);

    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);

    string contenttype = String.Empty;



    //Set the contenttype based on File Extension

    switch(ext)

    {

        case ".doc":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".docx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-word";

            break;

        case ".xls":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".xlsx":

            contenttype = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

            break;

        case ".jpg":

            contenttype = "image/jpg";

            break;

        case ".png":

            contenttype = "image/png";

            break;

        case ".gif":

            contenttype = "image/gif";

            break;

        case ".pdf":

            contenttype = "application/pdf";

            break;

    }

    if (contenttype != String.Empty)

    {



        Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;

        BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);

        Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);



        //insert the file into database

        string strQuery = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data)" +

           " values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery);

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = filename;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContentType", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value

          = contenttype;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Data", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = bytes;

        InsertUpdateData(cmd);

        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;  

        lblMessage.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";

    }

    else

    {

        lblMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;   

        lblMessage.Text = "File format not recognised." +

          " Upload Image/Word/PDF/Excel formats";

    }

}
```

**Updating**

```
private Boolean InsertUpdateData(SqlCommand cmd)

{

    String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager

    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    cmd.Connection = con;

    try

    {

        con.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return true;

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        Response.Write(ex.Message);

        return false;

    }

    finally

    {

        con.Close();

        con.Dispose();

    }

}
```

Comment: Value of type 'Long' cannot be converted to 'Integer'

Comment: changed to `Dim bytes As [Byte]() = br.ReadBytes(fs.Length)` and i get the same error where file upload control is null.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing this:

```
If (String.IsNullOrEmpty(validationMessage)) Then
      cmd = New SqlCommand("", conn)

            Dim imageData As Byte()
            Dim sFilePath As String = fuSelectedFile.PostedFile.FileName
            Dim ext As String = Path.GetExtension(sFilePath)
            Dim sFileName As String
            Dim sFileType As String

            'upload file to DB
            If (RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue = "0") Then
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(sFilePath) Then
                    If (ext = ".jpeg" Or ext = ".pdf" Or ext = ".jpg") Then

                        Try
                            'Read Image Bytes into a byte array 
                            'Initialize SQL Server Connection 
                            If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                                conn.Open()
                            End If

                            'Convert File to bytes Array
                            'Initialize byte array with a null value initially. 
                            Dim data As Byte() = Nothing
                            'Use FileInfo object to get file size. 
                            Dim fInfo As New FileInfo(sFilePath)
                            Dim numBytes As Long = fInfo.Length
                            'Open FileStream to read file 
                            Dim fStream As New FileStream(sFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                            'Use BinaryReader to read file stream into byte array. 
                            Dim br As New BinaryReader(fStream)
                            'When you use BinaryReader, you need to supply number of bytes to read from file. 
                            'In this case we want to read entire file. So supplying total number of bytes. 
                            imageData = br.ReadBytes(CInt(numBytes))

                            sFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(sFilePath)
                            sFileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(sFilePath)


                            'Set insert query 


                            'Execute the Query
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                        Catch ex As Exception
                            validationMessage = "The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " & ex.Message
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
                        End Try
                    Else
                        validationMessage = "Jpeg or PDF files only!"
                    End If

                Else
                    validationMessage = "No file selected!"
                End If

            End If
        End If
```